# Forcing a ScrollPane to calculate it's slider dimensions

Tags: java, css, canvas, javafx

It would be difficult to post the code I'm working with here, but this what I'm trying to do

I start with a 300x200 ScrollPane and a 300x200 Canvas, put canvas in scrollpane.

When a key is pressed, the key should be drawn on the canvas. When multiple keys are pressed, they are added in front of each other.

When the area for the key to be drawn extends the 300 width limit of the Canvas, the size of the Canvas is increased accordingly and the key is drawn in the new space and the slider is sent further to show the key being pressed. (essentially like Notepad or any code editor)

The issue is that the slider doesn't actually update it's bounds until about 10-15ms after the width of the content is increased. To compensate for this, I end up waiting 20ms than changing the slider but this is giving me alot of glitches (frames are choppy, other operations are occuring before that mess up slider position, etc.)

How do i force the extents of the slider to update so that I can display the new keys in the same frame that they are added?

e/ sample code

/*

```
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package javafxapplication11;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Arhowk
 */
public class JavaFXApplication11 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ScrollPane root = new ScrollPane();
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300,250);
        GraphicsContext ctx = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        ctx.setFill(Color.RED);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
        bp.setTop(canvas);
        root.setContent(bp);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        root.setFocusTraversable(true);
        root.setOnKeyPressed((a) -> {
            canvas.setWidth(600);
            ctx.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            ctx.fillRect(300,0,300,250);
            root.setHvalue(1);
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: better to share the code to reproduce the issue. The issue in your code itself.

Comment: added. On further review, i meant to say force the update of BorderPane not ScrollPane

Comment: Found it! bp.autosize()